# Comparing two dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that are structure wise equal.

Both has to following format:

```
file_name | country_name | country_code | .....
```

I want to compare the two, and get a percentage of equality for each column.

The second data frame is the test dataframe, that holds the true values. Some of the values are NaN, which should be ignored. So far I have a managed to compare the two, and get the total number of equal samples for each column, my problem is dividing each of them by the total number of relevant samples(That doesn't have NaN in the second dataframe), in a "nice way".

For example:

df1

```
file_name | country_name 
    1            a
    2            b
    3            d
    4            c
```

df2

```
file_name | country_name 
    1            a
    2            b
    3            nan
    4            d
```

I expect an output of 66% for this column, because 2 of the 3 relevant samples has the same value, and the 4th is nan so it is ignored from the calculation.

What I've done so far:

```
test_set = pd.read_excel(file_path)
test_set = test_set.astype(str)
a_set = pd.read_excel(file2_path)
a_set = a_set.astype(str)
merged_df = a_set.merge(test_set, on='file_name')
for field in fields:
    if field == 'file_name':
        continue
    merged_df[field] = merged_df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x[field + '_y'] == 'nan' else 1 if x[field + '_x'].lower() == x[field + '_y'].lower() else 0, axis=1)

scores = merged_df.drop('file_name', axis=1).sum(axis=0)
```

This gives me these(correct) results:

```
country_name      14
country_code       0
state_name         4
state_code        59
city              74
...
```

But now I want to divide each of them by the total number of samples that doesn't contain NaN in the corresponding field from the test_set dataframe. I can think of naive ways to do this, like creating another column that holds the number of not nan values for each of these column, but looking for a pretty solution.

Comment: what do you mean by "*structure wise equal*"? You should really provide a meaningful example

Comment: Meaning both dataframes looks exactly the same, but can hold different values

Comment: @mozway I've updated the question with more info

Comment: So the file_name values are unique? already in the same order index-wise?

Comment: Yes they are unique keys, I used numbers just for simplicity @mozway

Comment: OK, last question are all ids present in both tables? If not which one is the reference?

Comment: Yes all ids present in both tables. @mozway

Comment: Then you likely don't need a merge, see if my answer below works for you (or provide a counter-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have unique filenames I would use all vectorial operations, take advantage of index alignment:

```
# set the filename as index
df1b = df1.set_index('file_name')
# set the filename as index
df2b = df2.set_index('file_name')

# compare and divide by the number of non-NA
out = df1b.eq(df2b).sum().div(df2b.notna().sum())
```

Output:

```
country_name    0.666667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to merge you could use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["1", "a"],
    ["2", np.NAN],
    ["3", "c"]
])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ["1", "X"],
    ["100", "b"],
    ["3", "c"]
])

# expected:
# col 0: equal = 2, ratio: 2/3
# col 1: equal = 1, ratio: 1/2

df1 = df1.sort_index()
df2 = df2.sort_index()

def get_col_ratio(col):
    colA = df1[col]
    colB = df2[col]

    colA_ = colA[~(colA.isna() | colB.isna())]
    colB_ = colB[~(colA.isna() | colB.isna())]

    return (colA_.str.lower() == colB_.str.lower()).sum() / len(colA_)

ratios = pd.DataFrame([[get_col_ratio(i) for i in df1.columns]], columns=df1.columns)
print(ratios)
```

Or, using `pd.merge`

```
fields = df1.columns
merged = pd.merge(df1,df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)

def get_ratio(col):
    cols = merged[[f"{col}_x",f"{col}_y"]]
    cols = cols.dropna()
    equal_rows = cols[cols.columns[0]].str.lower() == cols[cols.columns[1]].str.lower()
    return equal_rows.sum() / len(cols)

ratios = pd.DataFrame([[get_ratio(i) for i in fields]], columns=fields)
ratios
```

Comment: This assumes they are ordered in the same order, I used merge because they are paired by the file name, but can come in different order of rows.

Comment: Ordering beforehand is not an option?

Comment: Ordering is fine

Comment: I added the sorting call (on index in this case), but you can replace it with sorting columns (`DataFrame.sort_values()`)

Comment: @sagi i added an approach using merge.